# How does conditional expectation relate to sufficiency?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, sufficient-statistics, conditioning

In what follows, I will disregard all "measure-theoretic niceties about conditioning on measure-zero sets", as my professor calls it. I just want to know if the following general idea, or even just something vaguely similar to it, is correct in any important cases of interest.

> **Question:** Does the indicator random variable of the conditional expectation:
>
> $$1_{\{ \mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B  \}  } $$
>
> *ever* equal the conditional expectation of the indicator random variable:
>
> $$ \mathbb{E}[1_{\{ \beta \in B  \}} | \hat{\beta}] \quad  $$
>
> (for measurable sets $B$)?

**Background:** The conditional distribution of a random variable $\beta$ given the variable $\hat{\beta}$ is determined by all random variables of the form $\mathbb{P}[\beta \in B | \hat{\beta}] = \mathbb{E}[1_{\{ \beta \in B  \}} | \hat{\beta}]$. So if one can show that all random variables of the form $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{ \beta \in B  \}} | \hat{\beta}]$ don't depend on a certain parametrization, then one can conclude that $\hat{\beta}$ is a sufficient statistic of $\beta$.

What I can show for a particular case is that the random variable $\mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}]$ doesn't depend on the choice of parametrization, i.e. its distribution doesn't, which is determined by the expectations of $1_{\{ \mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B  \}  } $, i.e. the values $\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B]$.

So if the type of relationship given above holds, then I would be able to use the fact I can show to conclude that sufficiency does indeed hold.

Unfortunately it's pretty clear that they can't be equal, since while both are random variables not scalars in general, taking the expectations of both, one gets that:

$$\mathbb{E}[1_{\{ \mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B  \}  } ] =\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B] $$ and $$ \mathbb{E} [\mathbb{E}[1_{\{ \beta \in B  \}} | \hat{\beta}] ] = \mathbb{E}[1_{\{\beta \in B \}}] = \mathbb{P}[\beta \in B] \,.$$

Note that their expectations being equal is a *necessary*, but not *sufficient* condition for the RVs themselves to be equal (in particular, I am ***NOT*** claiming that their expectations being equal implies that they themselves are equal).

So if their expectations are *not* equal, then we can conclude that they themselves are not equal. So there is not even a glimmer of hope for them being equal unless there is some reason to expect that $\mathbb{P}[\beta \in B] = \mathbb{P}[\mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B]$. (I think such a statement could make sense, since the fact that $\hat{\beta}$ is by assumption a measurable function of $\beta$ should mean that $\mathbb{E}[\beta | \hat{\beta}]$ and $\beta$ could both be restricted to some common $\sigma$-algebra of definition, namely the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\hat{\beta}$, which has to be contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\beta$, again because $\hat{\beta}$ is a function of $\beta$.)

The *necessary*, but ***not sufficient*** relationship:

$$\mathbb{P}[\beta \in B] = \mathbb{P}[\mathbb{E}[\beta| \hat{\beta}] \in B]$$

follows though directly [from the definition of a conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-.CF.83-algebra).

Comment: You should add `self-study` as a tag. And reflect upon the fact that an indicator function takes values only in $\{0,1\}$, while its expectation is a probability, taking values in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean `do not depend on the parameter of the distribution of $\beta$' ? Parametrization has a different meaning, like using $\theta$ versus $\log\theta$.

Comment: Question is ill formulated. A sufficiently statistic is a measurable map. One says "a statistic is sufficient for a parametric family of distributions, parametrized by say β, if...(certain properties hold)". So, in your statement "...β^ is a sufficient statistic of β...", β^ is a measurable map while β is a parameter? If β is a parameter, then $1_{\beta \in B}$ has no meaning. Assuming both β^ and β are both random variables, so that the expressions actually make sense, then the two quantities defined are clearly not equal in general.